# R data.table remove rows conditionally among groups

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I have this example dataset and the actual has millions of rows, so I'd appreciate a `data.table` solution but also a `tidyverse` solution would be fine:

```
dat1 = data.frame(name = c("X1", "X1", "X1", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2"), 
              year = c(2015,2016,2017,2015,2016,2016,2017,2017, 2018),
              choice = c("o","o","o","o","o","r","r","o","o")
)
dat1
```

The logic I need to apply is:

If for any name and year combination only choice `"o"` exists, retain the row with `"o"`.

If for any name and year combination choices `"o"` and `"r"` exist, retain row with `"r"` and drop row with `"o"`. I don't want to name `name` and `year` combinations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(dat1)
dat1[, .SD[all(choice == "o") | choice == "r",], by = .(name, year)]
#    name year choice
# 1:   X1 2015      o
# 2:   X1 2016      o
# 3:   X1 2017      o
# 4:   X2 2015      o
# 5:   X2 2016      r
# 6:   X2 2017      r
# 7:   X2 2018      o
```

(I generated this before looking at KarthikS's answer, but the logic and the results are identical.)

Answer (score 3):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
dat1 %>% group_by(name ,year) %>% filter(all(choice == 'o' )|choice == 'r')
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   name, year [7]
  name   year choice
  <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
1 X1     2015 o     
2 X1     2016 o     
3 X1     2017 o     
4 X2     2015 o     
5 X2     2016 r     
6 X2     2017 r     
7 X2     2018 o
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Karthik It works fine, I just accepted r2evans' answer as it's a `data.table` solution.

Answer (score 0):

An option is also to convert the column to `factor` with `levels` specified in the custom order and then select the `first` `levels` after dropping the levels with `droplevels`

```
library(dplyr)
dat1 %>%
     group_by(name, year) %>%
     filter(choice %in% levels(droplevels(factor(choice, 
           levels = c('r', 'o'))))[1])
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   name, year [7]
#  name   year choice
#  <chr> <dbl> <chr> 
#1 X1     2015 o     
#2 X1     2016 o     
#3 X1     2017 o     
#4 X2     2015 o     
#5 X2     2016 r     
#6 X2     2017 r     
#7 X2     2018 o
```

---

An equivalent option with `data.table` is

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat1)[dat1[, .I[choice %in% 
       levels(droplevels(factor(choice, 
           levels = c('r', 'o'))))[1]], .(name, year)]$V1]
```